# How does inheritance of variables work in Solidity?

Tags: inheritance, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

How exactly does inheritance work in Solidity?
I have the following code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract Golem {
    int public hp = 100;
    int internal attack = 20;
    int private attackMod = 2;

    function takeDmg(int dmg) public{
        hp = hp - dmg;
    }

    function attackBasic() public view returns(int){
        return attack * attackMod;
    }
}

contract FireGolem is Golem {}
```

The way I understand inheritance is, that basically all the code is taken and "copied" inside FireGolem.
But then what is the use of `private` variables? Since `private` variables "can't be seen in derived contracts".

(using Remix)
If I leave it as is and deploy the `FireGolem` then I can call the `attackBasic` function and get the value `40`. So it seems like I can access the `private` variable.

But if I add another function into the FireGolem:

```
function test() public view returns(int){
    return attack * attackMod;
}
```

then I would get an error, "Undeclared identifier", which would mean I can't access the variable.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The child contract (`FireGolem`) cannot access `private` variables of the parent contract (`Golem`) directly. That's the basic feature of `private` variables in Solidity ([docs page](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/contracts.html#state-variable-visibility) on visibility) as well as generally in OOP.

In this specific case, you're only able to read the value onchain because the parent contract already (sort of) defines a `public` getter of the `private` variable. If there was no `attackBasic()` function, the `FireGolem` contract would not be able to access the `attackMod` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

For public variables, the getter function will be automatically created. In your contract, for `hp`, you will have a getter function created

```
int public hp = 100;
```

but not for those

```
int internal attack = 20;
int private attackMod = 2;
```

If you deploy your contract you will have a function for the public variable

[image]

> But if I add another function into the FireGolem:
>
> ```
> function test() public view returns(int){
>     return attack * attackMod;
> }
> ```
>
> then I would get an error, "Undeclared identifier", which would mean I
> can't access the variable.

you cannot access the `attackMod` because it is private and no public getter set for it. Private variables can be used only inside its contract

- the reason why this is implemented in this case is, the contract creator does not want any derived contract to manipulate the private variable. If the contract creator wants to have the functionality to modify the variable, it could write a setter with some sort of validation logic